# Динамическое обновление части страницы. URL, история

Tags: php, javascript, html, вёрстка, frontend

Как сделать **динамическое** обновление части страницы?

Например, нажал на пункт меню, и загрузился определённный контент.
Необходимо, **чтобы не обновлялась страница**, **изменялся url** и **работала история** (кнопка "вперед", "назад").

Comment: Такое делается через history.pushState -
 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Comment: Лучше посмотреть все API https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API  кроме самого pushState понадобится еще перехватить событие popstate что бы по нему узнать, что начали двигаться по истории

Comment: А лучше использовать какой-нибудь готовый фреймворк, например Angular. Или библиотеку для роутинга. Что бы не создавать велосипеды на костылях.

Comment: Можно поподробнее насчет Angular?